# Undefined reference to ssh_packet_disconnect_callback: how to import it correctly?

Tags: c

C newbie question: I'm using `libssh` in my program. So far, I was able to compile it successfully using command:

```bash
gcc -o my_program my_program.c -L/usr/include/libssh -lssh
```

But after adding a new function, namely `ssh_packet_disconnect_callback()`, the compiler wasn't able to locate it.

Here's the code excerpt:

```c
#include <libssh/libssh.h>

ssh_session session;
session = ssh_new();

[...]

printf("Callback: %d\n", ssh_packet_disconnect_callback(session));
```

And the compiler's output:

```bash
my_program.c: In function ‘main’:
my_program.c:55:38: warning: implicit declaration of function ‘ssh_packet_disconnect_callback’ [-Wimplicit-function-declaration]
   55 |             printf("Callback: %d\n", ssh_packet_disconnect_callback(session));
      |                                      ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
/usr/bin/ld: /tmp/ccdzN7R4.o: in function `main':
my_program.c:(.text+0x21d): undefined reference to `ssh_packet_disconnect_callback'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

As I checked in the filesystem, here are the files:

```bash
ll /usr/include/libssh/
total 184
drwxr-xr-x  2 root root  4096 Jan  8 11:31 ./
drwxr-xr-x 57 root root 20480 Jan 10 11:41 ../
-rw-r--r--  1 root root 37913 Aug 26  2021 callbacks.h
-rw-r--r--  1 root root  6867 Oct 19  2018 legacy.h
-rw-r--r--  1 root root 31624 Aug 26  2021 libssh.h
-rw-r--r--  1 root root 20417 Aug 26  2021 libsshpp.hpp
-rw-r--r--  1 root root  1616 Dec 18 23:30 libssh_version.h
-rw-r--r--  1 root root 12791 Aug 26  2021 server.h
-rw-r--r--  1 root root 32433 Aug 26  2021 sftp.h
-rw-r--r--  1 root root  2763 Mar 15  2021 ssh2.h
```

Looking for the function didn't work though:

```bash
grep -rn '/usr/include/libssh/' -e "ssh_packet"
/usr/include/libssh/callbacks.h:510:typedef int (*ssh_packet_callback) (ssh_session session, uint8_t type, ssh_buffer packet, void *user);
/usr/include/libssh/callbacks.h:512:/** return values for a ssh_packet_callback */
/usr/include/libssh/callbacks.h:530:struct ssh_packet_callbacks_struct {
/usr/include/libssh/callbacks.h:536:    ssh_packet_callback *callbacks;
/usr/include/libssh/callbacks.h:543:typedef struct ssh_packet_callbacks_struct *ssh_packet_callbacks;
```

In the documentation, I found [source file](https://api.libssh.org/stable/packet_8h_source.html) which points to that method (check line #55). However, I couldn't find any usage examples.

The question: how to properly import the `ssh_packet_disconnect_callback()` function to the program?

Comment: A quick glance at the docs: https://api.libssh.org/master/group__libssh__callbacks.html#ga6b8722467c98b73a7d78c0ec055e740d
looks like ssh_packet_disconnect_callback is a typedef. It's not a function.
https://api.libssh.org/master/group__libssh__callbacks.html#ga8fd26956f4e2b9bc57cfef26c50e321b

Answer (score 2):

> But after adding a new function, namely ssh_packet_disconnect_callback(), the compiler wasn't able to locate it.

You did not add any new function.  You added a ***function call***.  (Or what you appear to intend to be a function all.)

The "implicit declaration of function" warning is telling you that at the moment that you reference `ssh_packet_disconnect_callback`, this symbol is completely unknown to the compiler.

The symbol `ssh_packet_disconnect_callback` is defined in `packet.h`, but you include `libssh.h`, not `packet.h`.  I took a brief look at `libssh.h` and it does not appear to directly include `packet.h`.  So, if you include `packet.h`, the warning will probably go away.

However, the linker error that you get later will in all likelihood remain, because there probably exists no such thing as a function `ssh_packet_disconnect_callback`.

The symbol `ssh_packet_disconnect_callback` is defined as follows:

```
SSH_PACKET_CALLBACK(ssh_packet_disconnect_callback);
```

The macro `SSH_PACKET_CALLBACK` is defined as follows:

```
#define SSH_PACKET_CALLBACK(name) int name (ssh_session session, uint8_t type, ssh_buffer packet, void *user)
```

I do not know why the ssh library defines this identifier in this weird way, because the definition makes it look like a function prototype, but the suffix `_callback` (and the convoluted mechanism through which it is declared) indicates that this is not a function that already exists for you to invoke; instead, it indicates that it this is the prototype of a function that you are supposed to write, and supply to libssh, so that libssh will invoke it back.